# sh -c doesn't recognize heredoc syntax

Tags: shell, sh, posix

I think the two commands below should be identical, but given the heredoc, the shell produces an error. Is it possible to pass a heredoc to the -c argument of sh?

#### heredoc example

```bash
/bin/sh -c <<EOF
echo 'hello'
EOF

# ERROR: /bin/sh: -c: option requires an argument
```

#### simple string example

```bash
/bin/sh -c "echo 'hello'"

# prints hello
```

Comment: Heredoc syntax puts the content on `stdin`, not interpolated into the command line.  Try deleting the `-c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands are not equivalent.

```bash
/bin/sh -c <<EOF
echo 'hello'
EOF
```

is equivalent to

```bash
echo "echo 'hello'" | /bin/sh -c
```

or, with here-string:

```bash
/bin/sh -c <<< "echo 'hello'"
```

but `sh -c` requires an argument. It would work with

```bash
echo "echo 'hello'" | /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post this as a comment but formatting code doesn't work well in comments. Using the accepted answer by @Benjamin W. as a guide, I was able to get it to work with this snippet

```bash
( cat <<EOF
echo 'hello'
EOF
) | /bin/sh
```

The magic is in how `cat` handles inputs. From the man page:

> If file is a single dash (`-') or absent, cat reads from the standard input.

So cat can redirect `stdin` to `stdout` and that can be piped to `/bin/sh`

Comment: This also work with line 1 as `cat <<EOF | /bin/sh`, line 2 `echo 'hello'`, and line 3 `EOF`.